Druid use Oracle db as metadata storage failed
I want to use oracle as metadata storage because mysql and postgres are not recommended in my company.
I add these properties into my common.runtime.properties:
druid.metadata.storage.type=oracle;
druid.metadata.storage.connector.connectURI=xxx;
druid.metadata.storage.connector.user=xxx;
druid.metadata.storage.connector.password=xxx;

But I get the follow error(it seems that druid doesn't have oracle extension):
 Unknown provider [oracle] of Key[type=org.apache.druid.metadata.MetadataStorageProvider, annotation=[none]], known options [[postgresql, derby]]

May I know whether druid support oracle as metadata storage?

"I want to use oracle as metadata storage because mysql and postgres are not recommended in my company" - I cannot fathom any sane reason why a company would want their people to use Oracle over Postgres. Can you explain the rationale here?

@Dai  this is because PostgreSQL lack encryption at rest capability. The data of our company is very important, so we need to use database which has encryption. Hope druid can support more databases as metadata storage like mongodb and oracle db.

Apache Druid only supports Derby, MySQL, and PostgreSQL for metadata storage, according to their official documentation:

Available metadata stores
Druid supports Derby, MySQL, and PostgreSQL for storing metadata


Derby is Druid's own metadata store, with the caveat that it is not yet ready for production use.

While Druid uses JDBC, that doesn't mean it supports using any JDBC driver for storing metadata, because programs use JDBC to pass raw SQL to an RDBMS, and every SQL dialect is specific to one particular RDBMS (e.g. you can't run MySQL's SQL against an Oracle server, even though you can use JDBC to speak to either RDBMS).

Apache Druid does not have native support for Oracle as a metadata storage option available. Instead, the error message specifies that the required Oracle extension is missing. Outside of the box, Druid natively supports PostgreSQL and Derby. Thus, if Oracle support is critical in your application, you would have to develop a custom extension or otherwise seek community-contributed plugins-though such efforts are not officially supported.

thanks, May I know where can I seek community-contributed plugins?
